# npm ERR! missing script: jasmine

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jasmine

I want to use Jasmine library to test my code, but I get an error message saying that I don't have jasmine added in the script part of package.json.
I would like to know what I need to add in the script part of package.json.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "cover": "jest --coverage",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "update-swagger-d-ts": "./node_modules/.bin/dtsgen src/swagger.json -o src/types/swagger.d.ts",
    "typecheck": "tsc",
    "jasmine": ""
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a full tutorial when it comes to working with React, and it is available as part of the [official Jasmine documentation](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/react_with_npm).

Mimally, you will need to install (`npm install --save-dev`) the following dev depencencies,

- cross-env
- enzyme (for shallow/mount rendering)
- enzyme-adapter-react-16
- jasmine-enzyme
- jsdom (to emulate browser within the node.js environment)
- And most importantly, jasmine

Then you initialise jasmine by running

```
jasmine init
```

The other steps regarding the configurations are available on the above tutorial, so please do look through them.

Last but not least, you may set up the test script on your package.json,

```
"scripts": {
    "jasmine": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jasmine",
}
```